# Is it possible to make Apache reload an SSL cert using PHP, without shell access?

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I've just found [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), while looking for an alternative to the [notorious](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html) StartSSL, to manage my DV SSL certs. Since the LE certs are short-lived, [I'd like to](https://serverfault.com/questions/814807/how-to-automate-lets-encrypt-on-limited-web-hosting) automate the renewal process.

I don't have shell access (just cPanel), nor built-in LE support from my hosting provider, so Certbot in manual mode [seems to be](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) the only way to go.

I've noticed cPanel's `/ssl/certs/` directory, containing all my certs. Now I'm thinking about a Cron job to run a PHP script that gets new certs and overwrites the expiring ones, but I'm not sure if this would work, since I'll need to make Apache reload the overwritten certs. Is it possible, using PHP?

Comment: You can't just cron-job the renewal-process using the letsencrypt service? (I guess not, just wondering). Also, you can cron-job the Apache-restart, so that's not really a problem (although you'll have to manually fix it if it doesn't come back up). But no, I don't think you'll be able to do this via PHP (at least nothing you can't already to via cron and shell-commands).

Comment: You can let PHP do anything you want, if you allow PHP to do so. Does the user group where the user of PHP resides in (likely www-data) have access to that directory? However.. it is my honest believe that certificates should be handled manually. It takes like what, 5 minutes of your time to update a years standing certificate?

Comment: @Xorifelse I disagree about handling the certs manually. That's what the whole Letsencrypt project is about and the main reason why their certificates are only valid for 3 months.

Comment: @Mike 3 months is indeed a short amount of time.

Comment: @Xorifelse Actually the `--manual` option is so discouraged that it is hidden from the Letsencrypt UI. It is found only in the online documentation.

Answer (score 1):

### Manually obtain the certificate

> **Dislaimer.** Letsencrypt [says](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/): We don’t recommend this option because it is time-consuming and you will need to repeat it several times per year as your certificate expires. For most people it is better to request Let’s Encrypt support from your hosting provider, or switch providers if they do not plan to implement it.
>
> **Dislaimer 2.** I don't actually have access to a cPanel server so I'm unable to test this. There may be errors. Please let me know and I'll correct them.

1. Install [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) on your local computer
2. Generate the challenge response:
   `$ certbot certonly --manual -d example.com --test-cert --staging`

   (Note: remove `--test-cert --staging` for a valid certificate)
3. You should then see something like:

   > Make sure your web server displays the following content at
   >   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/VnHBr_PVGfhu-jdX0NCKrgAcCeC9A-HVqFjMOUAf24Y before continuing:
   >
   > VnHBr_PVGfhu-jdX0NCKrgAcCeC9A-HVqFjMOUAf24Y.0l4s1uvmfEFHST9EqeW_AnsdrM7GmE0joLEjRGruG-8
4. Manually create and upload the file to your webroot as necessary
5. Go back to your computer and push <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue

If everything went well you should have a shiny new SSL certificate.

### Install the SSL Server Certificate Files

1. Login to cPanel
2. Click SSL/TLS Manager > Certificates (CRT) > Generate, view, upload or delete SSL certificates
3. In the Upload a New Certificate section click the Browse button and locate your SSL Server Certificate file. I believe this should be `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem`
4. Click the Upload button.
5. Click the Go Back link to return to SSL/TLS Manger.

Note: I don't see anything in the above instructions that mention what to do with the private key, however [this site](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/cpanel/install-ssl-certificates-with-cpanel-ssl-tls-manager) mentions an **"Upload a New Private Key"** link somewhere. Wherever that is you want to put your private key in there.

### Setup the Domain

1. Click SSL/TLS Manager > Setup a SSL certificate to work with your site. If this option is not available to you your ISP may have disabled it and you will need to contact them to complete your SSL setup.
2. From the Domain drop down menu select the domain that will use the SSL Certificate. The system will attempt to Fetch the SSL Certificate and corresponding private key.
3. Open the Letsencrypt intermediate key (`/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem`) in Notepad or other simple text editor (not Word). Copy-and-paste all the contents of the this file into the Ca Bundle (CABUNDLE) box.
4. Click on Install Certificate. You should receive a message that the certificate was successfully installed. If you receive an error you may need to contact your web hosting provider for additional support.

After the certificates are successfully installed cPanel should restart/reload the webserver so that the certificate is live.

Adapted from [here](https://www.geocerts.com/install/cpanel_11).

Comment: It's unfortunate I cannot favorite answers that I can get back to.

Comment: @Xorifelse You can favorite the question. It's not likely there will be other answers to it. However I would still discourage doing it this way if at all possible to automate the process or change hosts. I have probably 10-15 certs with Letsencrypt and I haven't touched anything in several months besides issuing new certificates, which is just a one-time thing and they'll all be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to solve here. First, how to obtain the certificate. And second, how to configure the webserver to use it. For both, I have two different solutions for you.

#### Use a computer with shell access to orchestrate

Let's say, you install certbot on your own computer. Let's also say, you have SFTP access to your webspace. You can use sshfs to mount that webspace and use certbot to automate obtaining a certificate:

```
#!/bin/sh

domain='example.org'

mkdir -p "/tmp/$domain"
sshfs "$domain:" "/tmp/$domain" -o nonempty
/opt/certbot/certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w "/tmp/$domain/public_html" -d "$domain"
# or later:
#/opt/certbot/certbot-auto renew
umount "/tmp/$domain"
```

Now you have obtained or renewed the certificate. You can use the Cpanel API to install it on the server:

```
domain='example.org'
ledir="/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain"
cabundle="$ledir/chain.pem"
crt="$ledir/cert.pem"
key="$ledir/privkey.pem"

cpanel_host='cpanel.example.com:2083'
cpanel_user=''

curl -u "$cpanel_user"\
 "$cpanel_host/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=SSL&cpanel_jsonapi_func=installssl&cpanel_jsonapi_user=$cpanel_user"\
 -d "domain=$domain" --data-urlencode "cabundle@$cabundle" --data-urlencode "crt@$crt" --data-urlencode "key@$key"
```

If you use your own desktop computer, this solution is probably not completely automated. I like this solution, because you don't have to store the admin password for the Cpanel account on the webserver. You also keep control over the certificate obtaining process and keys.

#### Use user-space ACME client on the server

There is acme.sh and there is Acme PHP and others which allow you to obtain the certificate from the server. My hosting provider allows me to run cron jobs so that I could run acme.sh to get certificates. I'm not sure if I could also access Cpanel's `uapi` command line tool through that. Otherwise you can use a pure PHP application with libcurl support to use the same API call as above to install the certificate. That would be completely automated, but I haven't tested that yet.